# What is the difference between time series analysis and panel data analysis?

Tags: time-series, panel-data

Do time series analysis and panel data analysis use the same analytic method?

If I know how to conduct time series analysis, what else I should know before I start to conduct panel data analysis? for example, different analytic methods or some important issues I should pay attention to, while conducting panel data analysis?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are differences between the terms "time series analysis" and "longitudinal data analysis"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93461). Or maybe this? ["Difference between longitudinal design and time series"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7110).